# OpenMP vs Native Threads when using Dynamic Loaded Plugins

Tags: c++, multithreading, plugins, openmp

I'm working on an scientific application (Discrete Dipole Approximation), to solve a problem across a problems set it end ups with multiple levels of nested loops that can be solved in parallel.

However there are also multiple methods in witch the different components of the problem can be solved. i.e. Different Array Layouts (Store Array of dipole on a Cubic Lattice, or other Non-Cubic Hexagonal etc. Lattice, or no Lattice) then the problem can be solved using different Congruent Gradient Solver Algorithms which will each have support for given array storage and may make use of FFT which can also be implemented in several manners. Anyway I handle this by using plugins to represent these different methods, witch are loaded in to a function pointer at run time.

Multithreading will exist both inside and outside of these functions. I known I can get this to work using Native Threads however the code will be extremely complex especially since in need to handle variable numbers of threads.

Also I will need a single output thread which will be IO bound rather than CPU bound but comparatively fast to the solution tasks this will write output to text files using output format further defined by plugins.

Also the individual solves need to be able to support a suspend to disk event handler this will in effect interrupt the loop that is being solved and dump the current state to disk. I.e. the solvers will be a class with a save/load function and  a suspend/resume function.

My question is how will these requirement impact on using OpenMP since this would be the best option as it would be easiest to use for secondary developers implementing different solvers (i.e. scientist not programers) however I'm not sure how OpenMP would work with my other requirements.